# Select query in django. How to retrieve a single value of a column?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a table in the database called `Student`. It has columns `id` (auto generated), `name`, `class` and `status`(pass/fail). I want to write a *SELECT* query to get the id of the student.

```
Select id 
from Student 
where name = "abc"
```

I want to write this in a **django project**. I have tried :

```
s=Student.objects.get(name="abc")
```

When T try `s.id` I get an error,

> **AttributeError**  QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'

Can anyone please help me how to write a select query in django, please?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `Student.objects.get` and not `Student.objects.filter` ?

Comment: Yes sir, i am using Student.objects.get . I checked it from Django tutorials ,to retrive a single row we have to use get() but not quite sure why i am getting this error.

Comment: Indeed, that is the way, the strange thing is that you get the error you would have gotten by using `filter` or another method returning a queryset.
Could you maybe post more code?

Comment: Do you happen to have a custom manager, which accidentally overrides the `get` ?

Comment: I dont have any other code. I am writing a function in which i need the id of the student to proceed. And here i am stuck.

Comment: @karthikr Thank you for your help. custom manager was overriding the get method.

Comment: Be carefull, you should only use get method on fields defined as unique. For example : ```name = Charfield(max_lenght=255,unique=True)```. If the name is not unique across your database django will throw an exception ```IntegrityError "Exception: Field is not unique"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should take care that you are importing the models.py document into the views.py file.

The query to get one Student by name should be:

```
import models
try:
    student = models.Student.objects.get(name="abc")
except:
    student = None  
    students = models.Student.objects.filter(name="abc")

if student:
    print student.id
else:
    if students:
        print "There are multiple users with this name"
    else:
        print "The user doesn't exist"
```

Try to get a Student by name, if it is not a unique field, is not a good practice. You should use a unique key to use the get method.

Comment: I was able to get the student.id thnx for the help. Further when i try to dump student.id into another table, i get an error ''unicode' object has no attribute 'id''